# How to extract dates from string fields in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have field that contains strings and has dates within.
e.g 
   Rate (20 Jan 2020 - 19 Feb 2020)
 or   Rate (6 Dec 2019 - 5 Jan 2020)
I need a Start Date and End Date out of the above strings in SQL. 
I can get Start Date but End Date (after the -) is a problem

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Avoid storing dates as `VARCHAR` at all cost. It's just asking for trouble.

Comment: Thanks I have solved the issue using                                                                  substring (substring(DREF, CHARINDEX(')',DREF)-11, LEN(DREF)),1,11) as EndDate

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

Its quite crude but it will get you answers:

```
select left('20 Jan 2020 - 19 Feb 2020',CHARINDEX('-','20 Jan 2020 - 19 Feb 2020')-1)
,right('20 Jan 2020 - 19 Feb 2020',len('20 Jan 2020 - 19 Feb 2020') -CHARINDEX('-','20 Jan 2020 - 19 Feb 2020')-1)
```

`CHARINDEX()` will give you the position of the character you desire, in this case the dash.  From there you can use `LEFT()`, `RIGHT()`, and `LEN()` to get the pieces out of the string that you need.

This works with SQLServer